# how to install magento2devbox-web

Tags: magento-2.1

Today I got mail from Magento regarding [Magento DevBox Beta](https://magento.com/blog/technical/set-your-magento-2-development-environment-faster?mkt_tok=eyJpIjoiWlRNNFlUSXlOVEF3TmpreiIsInQiOiJ5a1VPbVpvMWQ1RE43aVE2R2psUkJWWEhzTm5BZjJIejRtTnd4NEQyU1AwR1FPS0pFbkxqZlFKVmg3ck83UWVZNjZiUTlyQzRjeWRXaERLNHFpRmZFY0VDWTBDQ1RqbElNcTgrb3ozTnArbnRPVEc1ZjZUbzA3cEVlRERkWVg2OSJ9) for faster access the website and more features. I have downloaded the module, But Where I need to paste it and how to install it. I don't know?

was there anyone installed it? please guide me how to install it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install [docker](https://www.docker.com/products/docker) available for both windows and unix systems, which is what the DevBox works with. Essentially docker is just a container which wraps a piece of software in a complete filesystem that contains everything it needs to run.

Once you install the docker, open the docker command line interface `cd` to the directory where you have the devbox file and then run the sh/bat file `./m2devbox-init.sh` (for unix) or `./m2devbox-init.bat` (for windows), this will do everything for you. To then access the site you type `http://localhost:1749`.

These are pretty much the same instructions provided by Magento.

NOTE:

If you're not using windows 10, you need to install the [docker-toolbox](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-toolbox)

Comment: Is there alternate way My OS is Windows 8.1 E, it's asking Windows 10 E

Comment: @magentotwo updated my answer.

Answer (score -1):

At least initially I found there were some blockers to a successful install if you choose to also install Varnish. I had to modify the yml file according to this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2devbox-web/issues/55).